# Probability of a relay circuit becoming short circuited.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Given, the probability of X being switched on (it will connect with another terminal) is p,

how to calculate the probability for terminal-a and terminal -b being connected

For instance, if 1,2 both relays are closed, there will be a connection between a,b.

Probability that, 
i) 1,2 both are closed is,  $p^2$
 ii) 3,4 both are closed is, $p^2$
 ii) 1,4 both are closed is, $p^2$
 ii) 3,2 both are closed is, $p^2$

So, the probability that, one of these paths will remain active is, $4p^2$

And, the probability that, all of the relays will be closed, is $p^4$
So, the probability that, there will be a connection between $a$ and $b$, 
$P_{ab} = 4p^2 + p^4$

But, I realize that I am over counting some probabilities, as the my calculated value for $P_{ab}$ becomes greater than 1.

I am not sure where is the over count happening.

Comment: These are just $2^4 = 16$ configurations. One could examine them all and count.

Comment: Yes, Xi is the switch, and X doesn't play any role by itself.. Sorry, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $X = closed = TRUE$, in this simple case you have
$$
X_{\,a}  = \left( {X_{\,1}  \vee X_{\,3} } \right)\; \wedge \;\left( {X_{\,2}  \vee X_{\,4} } \right)
$$
and thus
$$
\begin{gathered}
  P\left( {X_{\,a} } \right) = \left( {P\left( {X_{\,1} } \right) + P\left( {X_{\,3} } \right) - P\left( {X_{\,1} } \right)P\left( {X_{\,3} } \right)} \right)\left( {P\left( {X_{\,2} } \right) + P\left( {X_{\,4} } \right) - P\left( {X_{\,2} } \right)P\left( {X_{\,4} } \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {2p - p^{\,2} } \right)^{\,2}  = p^{\,2} \left( {2 - p} \right)^{\,2}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me, how can I get the result in the approach that I started? Thank you.

Comment: It's okay, I figured it out from your equation that I can use ven diagram to calculate it as well.

Comment: @SalmanEstyak: yes, you can use Venn diagram (or other means), but when you will afford a bit more complicated circuits the only practicable way is AND/OR expressions, or [Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), etc., which have the advantage that can be input to SW programs.  As for your approach in the post, that is also possible but prone to errors (and inpracticable for complex situations): you missed in fact the cases 3closed+1open.

Answer (score 0):

Here, when we are doing, $p^2 + p^2 + p^2 + p^2$ , we are counting one of the possibilities,

from set theory, we know that,

$n ( A U B U C U D) = n (A) + n(B) + n(C) + n(D) - n(AU B UC ) - n (A U B U D) - n (A U C U D) - n (B U C U D) + n (A U B U C U D)$

If, $A, B , C ,D$ are events of being $(X1, X2)$ being connected, $(X3, X4)$, $(X1,X4)$, $(X3, X2)$ being connected and so forth,

And, if $P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = P(D) = p^2$
So,

We can derive that,

$p^2 + p^2 + p^2 + p^2 - p^3 - p^3  - p^3 - p^3 + p^4= 4*p^2 - 4*p^3 + p^4$